# Change color to a material receiving shadows

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to put a light in the entire scene to cast shadows. I have a problem because they do not like changing the color of the material. And the shadows do not appear.
how I can change the color of a MeshLambertMaterial material after adding it to the scene, and why not show me the light and shadows that should generate ?.
When I try to change the color of the material I get all black.

This is the code that I have:

```
  material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: "#FFFFFF",name:$scope.datosMunicipio[i].nombre} );
  objMesh = new THREE.Mesh( extrude_geometrY, material );
  objMesh.receiveShadow = true;

var lightAmbient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000);
scene.add(lightAmbient);

var luzDireccional = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x000000,1);
luzDireccional.position.set(1,1,1).normalize();
scene.add(luzDireccional);

objMesh.material.color.set("#FF0000"); //Ineed change the color
```

Comment: Use hex notation for colors: `color: 0xffffff`. `material.color.set( 0xff0000 )`. Your ambient light is black. Change it to `0x222222`. Your directional light is black. Change it to `0xffffff`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setHex` to apply a color in hex-notation:

`objMesh.material.color.setHex( 0xFF0000 );`

However you can `set` a `THREE.Color` like this:

```
var redColor = new THREE.Color( 0xFF0000 );
objMesh.material.color.copy( redColor );
```

Read more about colors: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Color

Comment: is the same with meshlamber?

Comment: @WestLangley whats the problem with ```color.set```?

Comment: is not working...    var redColor = new THREE.Color( 0x00FF00 );
                            
                
                 var squareMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ 
                    color:redColor
                   
                });   I did this and left with black color. you need to put lights or something to get the color I'm getting?

Comment: Either you need a light or you set the color for ```emissive``` on the material.

Comment: @FalkThiele Personal preference, I guess. You can change it back if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the color of the light. MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial are not effective to colors unless we externally add lights to it.

Comment: @Siddarha Raju entonces, qué es lo que puedo hacer?, no entiendo.

Comment: @user5115790 lightAmbient, luzDireccional tanto estas luces que ha creado son de color negro. Así que cambiar el color a blanco (0xffffff) y luego ver el resultado.